# 3-manifold rigidity?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

**Defintion:**
a $n$-manifold $M$  is said rigid if any homotopy equivalence $M\rightarrow N$ is homotopic to a homemorphism, where $N$ is an $n$-manifold.

The sphere $S^{3}$ and hyperbolic compact oriented $3$-manifold (without boundary) and the torus $T^{3}$ are rigid if I'm not wrong.

**Question:**
More generally, suppose that $M$ is a compact oriented $3$-manifold (without boundary) is it rigid ?

Comment: The lens spaces L(7,1) and L(7,2) are homotopy-equivalent but not homeomorphic, if I remember the number correctly.

Comment: I think that $M$ is rigid if its universal covering is contractible. This is predicted by the Borel conjecture, but probably it's known in dimension 3.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, rigidity holds for aspherical 3-manifolds (post-Perelman).

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77400/topological-rigidity-of-compact-manifolds-in-dimension-three?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Diffeomorphism of 3-manifolds](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8924/diffeomorphism-of-3-manifolds)

Comment: I suggest that you write your own answer to the question and mark it as OK, otherwise this question will get closed...