# Simple homotopy equivalent $3$-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let $M^3$ and $N^3$ be two oriented closed $3$-manifolds which are simple homotopy equivalent. Are $M^3$ and $N^3$ diffeomorphic? I was told that this follows from the geometrization conjecture, but I cannot find a reference.

Comment: There are very few $3$-manifolds which can be homotopy equivalent without being diffeomorphic. I think the only examples are lens spaces (and perhaps some connected sums). So it should be enough to check that non-diffeomorphic lens spaces are not simply homotopy equivalent, which I think follows from computing Reidemeister torsions.

Comment: See Ian Agol's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/9015/40804). The answer is yes and it is due to Turaev once one knows the geometrization conjecture.